# Arial and Courier not working on Ubuntu

Tags: css, ubuntu, fonts

I have a script which converts HTML to PDF. On Windows, it runs just fine.

But when I run the script on Ubuntu, the Arial and Courier fonts do not work correctly.

I presume this is because those fonts don't come with Ubuntu by default. That's fine, it's not a big deal.

I'm just wondering what I should change the following to, such that it will still work on Windows and use a font that is *close* to Arial and Courier respectively on Ubuntu?

```
            font-family: "Arial";
            font-family: courier;
```

Thanks

Comment: `font-family: Arial, courier, sans-serif;`? Or `font-family: Arial, sans-serif;` and `font-family: courier, monospace;` to use them separately. Does this work?

Comment: You could install [Microsoft Fonts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Microsoft_Fonts) for Ubuntu

Comment: @vsnyc Yeah, having the relevant fonts in your system is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Arial-esque font use

```css
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

and for the Courier-esque font use

```css
font-family: Courier, monospace;
```

These rules basically mean: take the first one if available, otherwise the next one, otherwise repeat until the end. It should work in normal CSS (not sure about your particular implementation, though).

`sans-serif` and `monospace` are browser or system dependent values for fonts that have been specified as those font classes (e. g. “DejaVu Sans” and “Ubuntu Mono”).

Comment: How can I test if sans-serif and monospace are installed on my Ubuntu? I tried the CSS change but there is no difference. It continues to use whatever the default font for Ubuntu is.

Comment: As I said, `sans-serif` and `monospace` are _not fonts_ but the default font as configured in the browser or the system. For example `sans-serif` could be configured to be `DejaVu Sans` or `Ubuntu` or whatever; then either of those fonts is selected automatically and the selected fonts are guaranteed to be installed (if not all fonts are deleted from the system).

Comment: Oh okay. How can I find out what the list of fonts I have installed is? (I only have command line access) - then I can pick one specifically?

Comment: @b85411 I’m not sure about that, unfortunately…

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Web Safe fonts. Here's a list of **Web Safe fonts** you can use:
[CSS Web Safe Fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)

Another way can be to **use a font from your web directory or fonts available on the web** from services like [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts),etc.

Here's its usage:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: fontName;
    src: url('/font/xyz.woff');
}
```

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) for reference on font face rules.

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) for getting started with Google Fonts.

Check this [page](http://www.cssfontstack.com/) for the Font Stack, showing the compatibility of fonts with different OS.